# Dice Roller Populate TextBox(s)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am still learning basic programming, literally off Visual Basic 2012 v11.

Here is what I am stumped on:
I made a stupid-simple Table-Top Role-Playing Character Log application.
I made a simple dice roller/"random number" procedure and set it to fill a ListBox with each button click of "ROLL" until the max of 6 was reached. That worked fine.

However, I changed my app to link with a database to store simple character information for all of the people playing,etc. Which means I now have separate dataset TextBoxes for each click of "ROLL". Would someone please advise me on the best way to populate one TextBox per button click with a maximum of 6 clicks, please?

I was using a loop to fill the ListBox with exactly 6 entries, and started that line of thought for filling the TextBoxes, but my late-night tired brain cannot find a way to fill ONE box EACH TIME instead of all boxes every single time. 
THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

My Code:

```
  Private Sub btnRoll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoll.Click
    'Roll a character stat up to 6 and add it to the lisbox
    'D20 is standard die, but stats below 6 are forgiven for this campagin
    Dim Dice As New Random
    Dim DiceRoll As Integer = Dice.Next(6, 20)
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim Stat As String = Convert.ToString(DiceRoll)

    Do While intCount < 7

    Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you've included enough information to give an informed answer.

From my understanding, you'd like to take the result of the roll, and input it into one of several textboxes (you haven't given a number of textboxes, but you'd like it done in less than 6 clicks).

Depending on what the different fields will be, you may want to include your calculations within the loop, along with this, to specify the output and then roll again X times within the loop:

```
Do While intcount < 7
    Select Case intcount
        Case 1
            txtBox1 = stat
        Case 2
            txtBox2 = stat
        Case 3
            txtBox3 = stat
        Case 4
            txtBox4 = stat
        Case 5
            txtBox5 = stat
        Case 6
            txtBox6 = stat
        Case Else
        'Nothing if not specified with other arguments. 

    'Roll again
    stat = Convert.ToString(Dice.Next(6,20))

Loop
```

Comment: I apologize for not providing enough information, in hindsight I should have submitted all that when I was more awake. Your assumption was pretty close though I needed to have one click per different box. So click once and box1, click 2 and box 2.  I had actually tried that method but after you posted your code, I do see an error that kept it from working properly. Well, at least I was on the right path lol. Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to ask any other questions you may have.